# How to customize field representation in django drf AutoSchema?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, schema, openapi

I am new to using Django drf schema generation. I installed and configured the schema according to the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/). It generates the OpenAPI schema. Now I want to customize the choice field representation and add some description in front of each field.
Current schema choice field is like below:

```
    condition:
          enum:
          - used
          - new
          - like new
          type: string
          nullable: true
```

I want the following:

```
    condition:
          enum:
          - used: "for used items"
          - new: "for new items"
          - like new: " brand new items"
          type: string
          nullable: true
```

In the documentation I could find little on how to customize the AutoSchema class but that was above my knowledge. I would be grateful if someone can help me on how can I override the schema methods to represent customize fields?